# How do I show the equivalence of the two forms of the Anderson-Darling test statistic?

Tags: statistics, improper-integrals

It's stated in many places regarding the Anderson-Darling test statistic, which is defined as

$$n\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(F_n(x) - F(x))^2}{F(x)(1 - F(x))}dF(x)$$

that this is functionally equivalent to the statistic

$$A^2 = -n - S$$

where

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{n}\left(\ln F(Y_k) + \ln(1 - F(Y_{n+1-k}))\right)$$

Note that $F_n(x)$ is the empirical distribution function and $F(x)$ is the distribution to which we are comparing the sample. $Y_k$ is the $k^{th}$ ranked element in the sample.

I even went so far as to read the original 1954 paper by Anderson and Darling and I have yet to discover how this equivalence was computed - these authors merely stated the equivalence too. I've tried writing out the numerator inside the integral and splitting into 3 integrals - I was only able to simplify one of them.

I have an inkling that maybe the Probability Integral Transformation should be applied, but I'm not really sure how. I'd really appreciate if anyone could give any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can prove it by dividing the integral into (n+1) integrals on the intervals $[Y_k; Y_{k+1})$.

Comment: Thanks - I was able to complete the proof thanks to this tip and by treating the empirical CDF as a constant when integrating.